# Multiple Desktops on Pi 3/Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I'm having a problem with my Pi3. I am able to create multiple desktops using the default GUI and use them in a session, but I cannot seem to make them a permanent feature as with my Pi and Pi2 machines. On a reboot, I'm back to a single desktop again.

What am I doing wrong? I can't find any reference to this issue in the knowledge base, but that could just be me using it wrong too. If so, I apologize in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: Without telling us how you created virtual desktops it is going to be difficult for us to know if you did it right or wrong.

Comment: If it helps and you are unaware, the "default GUI" on Raspbian is [LXDE](http://lxde.org/).

Comment: I enabled the right-click menu in the preferences applet, right clicked on the desktop and selected the option to make an additional desktop.

This was the method used in previous Pi releases (except the right-click menu options were on by default with the Model B, B+ and Pi 2 (all running wheezy).

I'm using the same method I always have, but the desktops are not persistent over reboots as they are with the older model Pi. Clearly there is some sort of configuration or permissions issue but finding it is proving problematical.

Comment: I seemed to have ObConf installed, but not its configuration menu. The instructions [here](http://rossdevitt.blogspot.com/2016/03/raspbian-multiple-desktops-easy-fix.html) were good. My right-click menu is a bit different now, but otherwise things seem to work. I set up four desktops, and gave them individual wallpapers and names. Rebooted my system and things were as I left them.